# How to use a mobile app to uninstall/install other mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic-framework

I need to create a mobile app to uninstall other app installed on the smartphone and install another app automatically.

The situation is:
I have a release app developed in ionic that sometimes needs to be updated because some plugins are modified. But the app is already installed in a lot of smartphones. I need to create that second app that knows when there is another version of the first app in a server and uninstall it and install the new version.
It's very important the act to uninstall and install the first app automatically.
The first app isn't in google store or apple store yet, I need to get it on a server.

There is a manner to use a plugin or root command to do this?

I prefer to develop it in ionic (IOS and Android), but I think that I'll need to do this in native.

I searched about HockeyApp, but the process uninstall and install isn't automatically.

Comment: "It's very important the act to uninstall and install the first app automatically" -- if by "automatically" you mean "without user involvement", this is not possible on Android, except perhaps on rooted devices, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: You might try this from your main app instead. Whatsapp and Facebook can upgrade itself without root permission on my Android phone.

Comment: You can't do this on iOS either; updates must come via the App Store process

Comment: you can't uninstall and install apps without user confirming he wants to do that. That's simple and clear.